# Need help with proof by induction, that $6n + 6 < 2^n$ for all $n > 5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation, induction, visualization

Not sure how to even wrap my head around this, and want more practice in proofs by induction.

So I let P(n) be "$6n + 6 < 2^n$" and prove by induction that it holds true for all $n > 5$.

Base case is $n = 6$. Then $6(6) + 6 < 2^6$ or $42 < 64$ so that is true.

Inductive hypothesis is that we assume P(k) holds for an arbitrary $k > 5$.

Inductive step I'm kinda lost on. All I know is that I have to show P(k + 1). Not sure how I'm able to even visualise or manipulate the expression to get what I want. Stuff is lost on me and I learn best with step-by-step tutorials with explanations as to WHY something is, instead of just being told it is.

All I can think of is $6(k + 1) + 6 < 2^{k+1}$. That's all.

Comment: By induction hypothesis $2^k>6k+6$. Now, write $2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k$...

Comment: @Mark Now I have $6k + 6 + 6 < 2 ⋅ 2^k$. There's a $6k + 6$ on the left hand side and a $2^k$ on the right hand side, which becomes much bigger when multiplied by 2 and will always surpass the 6 added to the left hand side. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show:
$6(n+1) < 2^n ~: ~n > 5.$

Since the original poster discussed induction, I am assuming that it is intended that $n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 6}}$.

For $n=6, 6 \times 7 < 2^6.$

There are two standard approaches to complete the induction analysis, focusing on what happens, as $(n) \to (n+1).$

The answer of Martin Argerami focused on how much was being **added** to each side.  This is one of the standard approaches.

The other approach, which focuses on how much each side is being multiplied by, is given below.

As $(n) \to (n+1),$ the expression $6(n+1)$ is multiplied by $~\displaystyle \frac{n+2}{n+1}~$ which is less than $(2)$.

As $(n) \to (n+1),$ the expression $2^{n}$ is multiplied by $(2)$.

So, the LHS is multiplied by a smaller factor than the RHS.  Therefore, if, for a given value of $(n)$, the LHS is smaller than the RHS, this inequality must also hold, as $(n)$ goes to $(n+1).$

Comment: I see now, giving an insight into how they change in value with respect to each other as n increases. Thanks! Stuff like this is hella hard and makes my brain hurt; would really help if there was a "hold my hand" tutorial for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the induction step, we assume the following to be true:
$$6k+6 < 2^k$$

Since this is assumed to be true, we can manipulate it in any way that retains the inequality.  For instance, we can multiply both sides by $2$ to turn that $2^k$ into a $2^{k+1}$:
$$12k+12 = 2(6k+6)<2(2^k) = 2^{k+1}$$

We want to compare this to $6(k+1)+6 = 6k+12$, so let's rewrite this inequality as
$$6k+(6k+12) < 2^{k+1}$$

and here, we're finished, because $6k > 0,$ so
$$6k+12 < 6k+(6k+12) < 2^{k+1}.$$

---

The above can now be condensed into a single set of inequalities as
$$6(k+1)+6 = 6k+12 < 12k+12 = 2(6k+6) < 2(2^k) = 2^{k+1}$$